# Determine $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}n/\sqrt[3]{n^{2}+k}$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

so i am kind of stuck in this limit $$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{2}+k}}\right)$$

because there's no $n^{3}$ to simplify with in that cube root

Thank you for your attention .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac n{\sqrt[3]{n^2+k}}>\sum_{k=1}^n\frac n{\sqrt[3]{n^2+n}}=\frac{n^2}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+n}}>\frac{n^2}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+n^2}}=\frac{n^2}{2^{2/3}n^{2/3}}=2^{-2/3}n^{4/3}$$

Thus, as $n\to\infty$, it diverges.

Comment: Hello again buddy . i still dont agree with $\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^{2/3}}\sim(n+1)^{4/3}$ but if the first one bigger than the last one that would be interesting .

Comment: @AymanErroutabi How about now?

Comment: .Result is more satisfying than my grades ... thank you

Comment: @AymanErroutabi Well, I spend all of my time doing this instead of my math homework.  I wonder who's in the better boat.

Comment: start doing this for money so you will get paid by doing what u love most and good luck abt ur homeworks

Comment: @AymanErroutabi I should.  I tutor my friends for free...but then they buy me coffee.  :-/

Comment: NExt time you do it more professional not just friends but their friends too .. u can even start giving help to students like me by skype and u get paid for it . i mean if u r really into this then seize this opportunity and put everything on it .

Comment: @AymanErroutabi So... what's your Skype?  XD (not serious at all)

Comment: and you can be a joker too that would suit you well lol jk

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $n/(n^2 + k)^{1/3} \ge n/(2n^2)^{1/3}.$

Comment: i still dont get it :/ ..

Comment: Maybe the inlined fractions are too difficult to read?  This is more or less the same expression as in Simple Art's solution, with a looser inequality (but still plenty sufficient to do the job).  The point is that the denominator $\sqrt[3]{n^2+k}$ is less than $\sqrt[3]{n^2+n^2} = \sqrt[3]{2n^2}$, since $k < n^2$, so the overall fraction is less than $\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{2n^2}}$.  Since that fraction is greater than $1$, we are adding $n$ copies of a quantity greater than $1$, and as $n \to \infty$, that sum increases without bound.

Comment: And now @SimpleArt's solution uses the same looser inequality. :-)

Comment: @BrianTung Sh... I just noticed how much simpler it is.  :-)

Comment: @BrianTung oh now i see how he managed to do it thank you guys